# isolation between lcd 20*4 lcd and tm4c123

Tags: lcd, isolation, controller

power suply required for my launchpad is 3.3 v and that required for lcd is 5 v. I want to isolate lcd and launchpad. What should I do? 
do i need to put optoisolator between each pin of lcd and controller?

Comment: I guess you really don't want to isolate them in the usual sense and just want to know how to use a 5 V LCD with a 3.3 V microcontroller? It'd be worth adding details on the LCD and how you plan to connect them (SPI / 4-bit / 8-bit etc).

Comment: if you want true isolation rather than changing the voltage of the interface between them like @PeterJ look into opto-isolators.. great for SPI.. not so great for 8-bit buses because you need an opto-isolator for every bit and control bits...

Comment: Why do you want isolation rather than just level translation?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what you are seeking is not truly isolation but level conversion.  Depending on the number of pins (typically one can use 8-bit or 4-bit data for LCD control) and direction (most of your pins are probably unidirectional), you can search for level converters at any of the semiconductor manufacturers' web sites such as [this one](http://www.ti.com/logic/docs/translationresults.tsp?sectionId=458&voltageIn=3.3&searchDirection=2&voltageOut=5.0&Search=Search) for Texas Instruments.

Alternatively, I believe the part on that board is 5V tolerant, so you might want to read [this application report](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spma053/spma053.pdf) on what that means and how it might apply to your situation.  In brief, 5V tolerant GPIO pins can generally be used as inputs, but an external pullup and open drain operation are likely to be required for output.  It may be possible that you wouldn't need anything but a few resistors to drive the LCD.